# Python String .strip() function returning wrong output

Tags: python, string, strip

I have the following string

```
'file path = data/imagery/256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478/256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478_B02_10m.tif'
```

I am trying to get `256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478_B02_10m.tif` from the string above

but if I run

```
os.path.splitext(filepath.strip('data/imagery/256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478'))[0]
```

It outputs `'_B02_10m'`

Same with `filepath.rstrip('data/imagery/256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478')`

Comment: Try using your_string.split('/')[-1]. This should give you 256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478_B02_10m.tif as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want all the string data after the `/` you can always use string.split. This spits your string into a list of strings split on the split string. Then you would only need the final item of this list.

```py
string_var.split("/")[:-1]
```

See more official python docs on string.split [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 1):

Python's strip doesn't strip the string in the argument but uses it as a list of characters to remove from the original string see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

EDIT: This doesn't provide a meaningful solution, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using strip you should use string.split()

Following piece of code gets you the required substring:

```
filepath = "data/imagery/256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478/256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478_B02_10m.tif"
print(filepath.split('/')[-1])
```

Output:

```
256:0:10.0:34:26:-1478_B02_10m.tif
```